# How to replace array_value?

Tags: php

```
$arr = ["250","250","500","500","250"];
```

Here is my `$arr` array. I want to replace 300 instead of 500.

Sample:

```
["250","250","300","300","250"]; //Output
```

### Here is my code

```
$length = sizeof($arr);

for($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++)
{

 if($arr[$i] <= 300)
 {

 }
 else
 {
      $replace = array($i => "300");
      array_replace($arr, $replace);
 }

}
```

Comment: Please provide a question. It is not clear what you want to find out.

Comment: I want ["250","250","500","500","250"] this array replace to ["250","250","300","300","250"]; using for loop or foreach

Answer (score 3):

You should use the `str_replace()` function, that allows you to replace a value with another one in both strings and arrays.

In your case it would be:

```
$arr = str_replace("500","300",$arr);
```

Comment: Just know this will replace the `500` in `5000` with `300` yielding `3000`, `50015` to `30015`, etc...

Answer (score 0):

you could use `array_replace()`, but it works not by value, rather by position, and `array_replace()` returns a new array rather than mutating the original one.

you could modify the else part of your code like below, since you were not using the modified array;

```
 ....
 ....
 else
 {
  $replace = array($i => "300");
  $arr2 = array_replace($arr, $replace);
  var_dump($arr2);//this holds the replaced array
 }
```